# Making a rectangle bounce off a canvas wall

Tags: javascript, html, object, canvas

All I need is to have this object travel left and right across the top of the canvas. Currently it spawns and travels right absolutely fine, then stops once it reaches the right edge of the canvas.

```
//mainEnemy Variables
        var mainEnemy_x = 10;
        var mainEnemy_y = 10;
        var mainEnemyHeight = 50;
        var mainEnemyWidth = 25;
        var mainEnemyRight = true;
        var mainEnemyLeft = false;
        var mainEnemy_dx = 2;

//Drawing the Main Enemy
    function drawMainEnemy()
    {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(mainEnemy_x, mainEnemy_y, mainEnemyHeight, mainEnemyWidth);
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

//Movement speed of mainEnemy
            if(mainEnemyRight && mainEnemy_x < canvas.width-mainEnemyWidth) 
            {
                mainEnemy_x += 5;
            } 
            else if(mainEnemyLeft && mainEnemy_x > 0) 
            {
                mainEnemy_x -= 5;
            }

            //mainEnemy moves across the top of the canvas
            if(mainEnemy_x + mainEnemy_dx - mainEnemyWidth > canvas.width) 
            {
                mainEnemy_dx = -mainEnemy_dx;
            }



            ball_x += dx;
            ball_y += dy;
            mainEnemy_x += mainEnemy_dx;
            }
```

This is all the code relevant to the object I need help with. I've tried just reversing it's `x` movement, with the `mainEnemy_dx = -mainEnemy_dx;` line, but this isn't working. I can see this code is an absolute mess at the moment, I just need to get it working then time for some serious cleanup.
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please define "this isn't working." What does it do now? What's wrong with it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to describe what it does currently. It seems to reach the right canvas side and vibrates or jitters, stuck halfway outside of the canvas. it remains jittering until the game terminates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have two movement systems. One with the left and right flags and constants added or subtracted from x and the other with dx. You should just use one or the other, the latter being simpler.

For the jitter, you have to either also check that the current dx is positive when going over the right by border (and negative on left) and then switch the sign, or move the object left when a collision with right border is found.

At the moment you are moving the object 7 units right every time, then when border is found only dx is used (2 or -2) but since your object can be over the border it might vibrate between 2 and -2 always. But at least the right branch will always try to move 5 units right even when dx is negative.

Using a debugger to step through the code and inspecting the variables and branches taken while vibrating on the right edge will show exactly how it behaves.